# How to use one class information in another class C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, for-loop

i'm a beginner in C++ and just wanted to know **if it is possible** for me to put the calculation in the last "for" loop that uses the name,amount and weight from the "Product" class to calculate the total and price in another class that would be titled "Price".
Sorry for the weird question i am just confused as to how to use classes with one another and if it is possible to do so...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Product
{
public:
    string name;
    int amount;
    float weight;
    void get()
    {
        cout << "Give product name,amount and weight : " << endl;
        cin >> name >> amount >> weight;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << name << " - "<< amount<<" , " <<weight <<" kg"<< endl;
        cout << "--------" << endl;
    };
};
int main()
{
    Product p[100];
    int n;
    cout << "Give the number of products you want to get : " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p[i].get();

    }
    cout << "Product display: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p[i].print();
    }
    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nPrice of " << p[i].name << " " << p[i].amount * p[i].weight << " $" << endl;
        total = p[i].amount * p[i].weight + total;
    }

    cout << "\nTotal: " << total << "$" << endl;

    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to add a `getPrice` method to class `Product`.  Why not give that a try?

Comment: Because its for a homework where it would be good to add/use another class not just 1 but you are correct about the making sense part,thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Its fine to have such questions when you are a beginner. There are few points I would to mention.

1. In your example there is no need of creating a separate class just
   for calculating the price. Calculation of price is a flow/method/set
   of instructions. So the logic of calculation of price should be a
   method and that too in the same class i.e. `Product`.
2. Secondly here the total price for for all the products is common for
   the class i.e. it is not different for different objects of the class. So
   here you need to create a `static` variable under the class which will
   carry the total price of all the products.
3. You can just create a `static` function in the Product class and pass
   the array of product as an argument and loop through the products to
   calculate the total price and store it in the static variable.

Hope this clears your doubt.